# Pass parameters to controller in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using following code to get values of some controls in View and passing that values to controller.

```
$('#jqxTree').on('select',
                    function (event) {

                         var args = event.args;
                        var treeOne = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('getItem', args.element);
                        var treeTwo = $('#jqxTree2').jqxTree('getSelectedItem');
                        var firstId = treeOne.id;
                        var secondId =treeTwo.id;
                        //alert(firstId + secondId);
                        $("#DVTContainer").attr('src', "@Url.Action("MotionChart", "Chart", new {data=treeOne.id,location=treeTwo.id })");
                    });
```

Following line results in error in above code.
 `$("#DVTContainer").attr('src', "@Url.Action("MotionChart", "Chart", new {data=treeOne.id,location=treeTwo.id })");`
Please help me how to solve it.

Comment: DVTContainer is an IFrame element

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
        url: /Home/AddSomething,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { value1 = "value1", value2 = "value2" },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.data);
        }
    });
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult AddSomething(string value1, string value2)
{
    return json(new { data = value1 + value2 });
}
```